# django admin site logging in error: CSRF verification failed. Request aborted

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn, django-rest-auth

When I try to log in to Django admin site I get the following error:

> CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
> You are seeing this message because this site requires a CSRF cookie when submitting forms. This cookie is required for security reasons, to ensure that your browser is not being hijacked by third parties.
> If you have configured your browser to disable cookies, please re-enable them, at least for this site, or for “same-origin” requests.

I'm using `Django 4.2.5`. I can login on my local machine. However, I can't login to the site running in the server. I have added the following settings to my `settings.py` file

```
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ["https://*.mydomain.ir","http://*.mydomain.ir","http://127.0.0.1","http://localhost","http://127.0.0.1:8000"]
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = False
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = None
CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN = 'mydomain.ir'
if os.environ.get("IS_SERVER", "False") == "True":
    SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = ['*']
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = False
CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'
```

I'm using `Nginx` and `Gunicorn`.
here's my `Nginx` config file:

```
server {
  server_name               api.mydomain.ir;
  listen                    80;
  location / {
    proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    proxy_set_header        Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
  }
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.ir/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.ir/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

I have tried clearing browser's cache but it didn't work.
I'm also using Django Rest Framework:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ],
}
```